# New to smartface. Looking for concrete examples to get me going

Tags: smartface.io

I started working with the free version to get a feel it, and to see if this is worth pursuing. I'm seeing some inconsistencies or maybe I'm just not "getting it". For example, I am putting together a page and trying to put in a menu. The documents state that there are several menu options, yet I don't see anything from the object list for a "menu" (it simply doesn't exist). So I'm not sure how you even do that.

I'm not very impressed with the documentation as it doesn't seem to explain anything in details. For example, the documentation states a menu can be done, and there are several options, but doesn't show you how to do it. Also looking for swiping ability. Again, the document says you can do it, but doesn't really go into detail on how to make the pieces fit. Does anyone know of any real documentation on how to work smartface?

I'm new to mobile development, but I have many of years of programming in different languages, so I thought this wouldn't be that complex. If someone has any good full-scale documentation on this product, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

-Jim

Comment: The [help/on-topic]  clearly says that questions asking us to find tutorials or off-site resources are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
At the time of this post, Xamarin was a paid software and Smartface was really the best option to use. Right now, Xamarin is open-source and I'm using it for quite a while... I'm pretty sure that its worth the time to learn C# and understand Xamarin, it has a better language, better support, more features, more platforms and its essentially free.

---

Yeah, Smartface's documentation doesn't cover ALL possibilities. I think it's because they have a paid license that unlocks "Smartface University" (tutorials), but if you have programming experience, shouldn't be too hard to learn by yourself, just take a look at all their guides and some main functions of the API and take your time to understand Smartface's logic. 
And yeah, it have some inconsistencies, but you can develop for Android and iOS with the same code, so it would be very hard to make it 100% consistent.

Yet, in terms of functionality, I didn't find any other IDE that did what Smartface does. If you want to build Native Android and iOS apps with a single code-base, Smartface is your best option.

Smartface Guides: https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/ 
Smartface API: http://docs.smartface.io/

By the way, I couldn't understand what you mean by "menu" and "swiping ability". If you clarify that, I could help :)